# Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/hadoop/fs/FSDataInputStream

Tags: hadoop, apache-spark

I'm submitting remote spark jobs to the Hadoop cluster. But getting below error message help me to solve this.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/hadoop/fs/FSDataInputStream
    at org.apache.spark.Logging$.<init>(Logging.scala:162)
    at org.apache.spark.Logging$.<clinit>(Logging.scala)
    at org.apache.spark.Logging$class.initializeIfNecessary(Logging.scala:103)
    at org.apache.spark.Logging$class.log(Logging.scala:50)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.ApplicationMaster$.log(ApplicationMaster.scala:635)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.ApplicationMaster$.main(ApplicationMaster.scala:649)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.ExecutorLauncher$.main(ApplicationMaster.scala:674)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.ExecutorLauncher.main(ApplicationMaster.scala)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.hadoop.fs.FSDataInputStream
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:331)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    ... 8 more
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was with the classpath.

I've added below code to the application and it solved the issue:

```
.set("spark.hadoop.yarn.application.classpath",
                                     "/etc/hadoop/conf,"
                                             + "/opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH-5.7.1-1.cdh5.7.1.p0.11/lib/hadoop/*,"
                                             + "/opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH-5.7.1-1.cdh5.7.1.p0.11/lib/hadoop/lib/*,"
                                             + "/opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH-5.7.1-1.cdh5.7.1.p0.11/lib/hadoop-hdfs/*,"
                                             + "/opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH-5.7.1-1.cdh5.7.1.p0.11/lib/hadoop-hdfs/lib/*,"
                                             + "/opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH-5.7.1-1.cdh5.7.1.p0.11/lib/hadoop-mapreduce/*,"
                                             + "/opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH-5.7.1-1.cdh5.7.1.p0.11/lib/hadoop-mapreduce/lib/*,"
                                             + "/opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH-5.7.1-1.cdh5.7.1.p0.11/lib/hadoop-yarn/*,"
                                             + "/opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH-5.7.1-1.cdh5.7.1.p0.11/lib/hadoop-yarn/lib/*,"
                                             + "/opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH-5.7.1-1.cdh5.7.1.p0.11/lib/spark/*,"
                                             + "/opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH-5.7.1-1.cdh5.7.1.p0.11/lib/spark/lib/*")
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're using a Spark distribution that was pre-built for user-provided Hadoop. Try downloading a distribution that says "Pre-built for Hadoop 2.x or later", where x would be your existing Hadoop cluster version, and see if it works for you.

Comment: I'm using CDH Cluster. I've installed the spark using the parcels.

Comment: Sorry, don't have experience with CDH, but I had the same error on my standalone Spark cluster that was successfully resolved as described above.

Answer (score 0):

To resolve this issue  run spark with the following command:

```
/usr/local/spark/bin/spark-shell
```